# Invert Top Rounded Borders to Create Bowl Effect

Tags: html, css

I have a div with rounded corners but I would like to invert these rounded corners to create a bowl effect.

Here is what I currently have:

```css
html{
  background:red;
}

#test {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 150px;
  border-top-left-radius: 50%;
  border-top-right-radius: 50%;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

So instead, I would like it to look like:

[image: Border Example]

Is this even possible with CSS?

### Update

If not already clear, the 'red' is meant to illustrate the rest of the body of the page and will need to be transparent

Comment: have border-bottom-radius to red container instead of blue..

Comment: So what your saying is: you want a transparent bowl-like "cut-out"?

Comment: the duplicate shows the opposite. did you look for something of that kind ? http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/yeRMLZ

Answer (score 1):

Change `top` to `bottom`.

border-*bottom*-left-radius: 50%;
border-*bottom*-right-radius: 50%;

**Edit:**

See [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xzbd9mL8/) then.

Comment: Sadly that is not what I am looking for... I am trying to 'punch' a bowl shape out of a div. This cannot be achieved by simply changing the border radius to border-bottom etc...

Comment: Does the outer div *have* to be `html`? If not, make two `div`s with the same height.

Comment: eh??? What do you mean?

Comment: `html {...}` you are selecting the html tag.

Comment: It should be pretty clear that the HTML is meant to represent the rest of the body of the page i.e. it will be transparent so adding a border-bottom radius to it will have absolutely no effect.

Comment: Likewise: https://jsfiddle.net/xzbd9mL8/1/

Comment: @BenCarey i think he meant this : https://jsfiddle.net/xzbd9mL8/2/ no extra markup nor pseudos involved, the simpliest way ...

Answer (score 1):

Create a pseudo element and rotate it by 180deg.

```
html {
  background: red;
}

#test {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 150px;
  background: blue;
}

#test::before {
  content: "";
  border-top-left-radius: 50%;
  border-top-right-radius: 50%;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p25s7zep/)**

Comment: This is exactly the 'sort' of thing I was looking for, some clever way of manipulating the pseudo classes. However, there is on thing that makes this a few steps harder and that is the red is actually meant to be representing transparency. So actually, what I would like to do, is punch a bowl shape in the blue div. Is this even possible?

Comment: @BenCarey AFAIK, there are all stupid tricks like I mentioned. I suggest you to go with SVGs instead. They are plain and straightforward.

Comment: SVG is a great option. otherwise, making use of two elements, or a pseudo element is probably the best option. The spec does not really support what you are trying to do, so some hacky css backflips are going to be required.